# XOR programming puzzle advice

Tags: c++, xor, bit

Given a long int *x*, count the number of values of *a* that satisfy the following conditions:

*a* **XOR** *x* > *x*  
0 < *a* < *x*

where *a* and *x* are long integers and **XOR** is the bitwise XOR operator

How would you go about completing this problem?

I should also mentioned that the input x can be as large as 10^10

I have managed to get a brute force solution by iterating over 0 to x checking the conditions and incrementing a count value.. however this is not an optimal solution...

This is the brute force that I tried. It works but is extremely slow for large values of x.

```
 for(int i =0; i < x; i++)
 {
      if((0 < i && i < x) && (i ^ x) > x)
          count++;    
 }
```

Comment: It would be great if the downvoters could mention the reason for their vote, otherwise we would have to call them awkward.

Comment: Not downvoter, but this has nothing to do with programming whatsoever. This is a mathematical fact about numbers that needs a proof.

Comment: For x > 0, any bit that is 1 in a and 0 in x will cause a ^ x > x, except the MSB which will cause it to be negative.

Comment: This is not true, if x= 10 (1010) and a = 3 (0011).. 10 xor 3 = 9. Am I understanding you correct there?

Comment: Ok so here's a hint. Suppose you know the answer for some number `x`. Can you now compute the answer for `2x`? What about `2x+1`?

Comment: Thats the problem, I am not sure of how to calculate it without using the brute force in the OP

Comment: The `(0 < i && i < x)` within the `if()` is entirely redundant. Remove it and/or compile with `-O2` and you should get the result within a few seconds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
long long NumberOfA(long long x)
{
    long long t = x <<1;
    while(t^(t&-t)) t ^= (t&-t);
    return t-++x;
}


long long x = 10000000000;
printf("%lld ==> %lld\n", 10LL, NumberOfA(10LL) ); 
printf("%lld ==> %lld\n", x, NumberOfA(x) );
```

***Output***

```
10 ==> 5
10000000000 ==> 7179869183
```

[Link to IDEOne Code](http://ideone.com/6yw2Zz)

---

Trying to explain the logic (using example 10, or `1010b`)

- Shift x to the left 1. (Value 20 or `10100b`)
- Turn off all low bits, leaving just the high bit (Value 16 or `10000b`)
- Subtract x+1 (`16 - 11 == 5`)

---

**Attempting to explain**
*(although its not easy)*

Your rule is that `a ^ x` must be bigger than `x`, but that you cannot add extra bits to `a` or `x`.
(If you start with a 4-bit value, you can only use 4-bits)

The biggest possible value for a number in N-bits is `2^n -1`.
*(eg. 4-bit number, 2^4-1 == 15)*
Lets call this number **B**.

Between your value `x` and **B** (inclusive), there are **B**-`x` possible values.
*(back to my example, 10.  Between 15 and 10, there are 5 possible values: `11`, `12`, `13`, `14`, `15`)*

In my code, `t` is `x << 1`, then with all the low bits turned off.
*(`10 << 1` is `20`; turn off all the low bits to get `16`)*

Then `16 - 1` is **B**, and **B** - x is your answer:
*(`t - 1 - x,` is the same as `t - ++x`, is the answer)*

Comment: This is however providing an incorrect answer (AFAIK) for 10000000000, it should be 7179869183 but instead I get 737418239

Comment: My newest revision gets: `7,179,869,183`

Comment: That may be about the ugliest, weirdest bit-manipulating code I've done in a long time.   :)  Interesting problem!

Comment: Haha, would you mind explaining how you got to this answer, like what was you thought process etc. Thanks

Comment: Down-Voter?  Want to comment?

Comment: Great explanation! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

One way to look at this is to consider each bit in *x*.

- If it's 1, then flipping it will yield a smaller number.
- If it's 0, then flipping it will yield a larger number, and we should count it - and also all the combinations of bits to the right.  That conveniently adds up to the mask value.

```
long f(long const x)
{
    // only positive x can have non-zero result
    if (x <= 0) return 0;

    long count = 0;

    // Iterate from LSB to MSB
    for (long mask = 1;  mask < x;  mask <<= 1)
        count += x & mask
            ? 0
            : mask;

    return count;
}
```

We might suspect a pattern here - it looks like we're just copying *x* and flipping its bits.

Let's confirm, using a minimal test program:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

int main(int, char **argv)
{
    while (*++argv)
        std::cout << *argv << " -> " << f(std::atol(*argv)) << std::endl;
}
```

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 0
2 -> 1
3 -> 0
4 -> 3
5 -> 2
6 -> 1
7 -> 0
8 -> 7
9 -> 6
10 -> 5
11 -> 4
12 -> 3
13 -> 2
14 -> 1
15 -> 0
```

So all we have to do is 'smear' the value so that all the zero bits after the most-significant 1 are set, then xor with that:

```
long f(long const x)
{
    if (x <= 0) return 0;
    long mask = x;
    while (mask & (mask+1))
        mask |= mask+1;
    return mask ^ x;
}
```

This is much faster, and still O(log n).

Comment: This is also a great solution with a great explanation, thank you.